# Where exactly does a python function's return value go?

Tags: python, function, return, conditional-statements

My Rock Paper Scissors code doesn't work and I'm assuming it's because I'm using the return value incorrectly. What should I do?

EDIT, so I've stored the return like this

```
def results (x, y):
if (x == "R" or x == "rock" or x == "r" or x == "Rock" or x == "ROCK") and (y == "S" or y ==  "s" or y == "Scissors" or y == "SCISSORS" or y == "scissors"):
    winner = 1
    return winner
```

But how do I get "winner" to print outside of the function?

OLD

```
player1 = input ("Player 1: Please enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors:")

player2 = input ("Player 2: Please enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors:") 

def results (x, y):
 if (x == "R" or x == "rock" or x == "r" or x == "Rock" or x == "ROCK") and (y == "S" or y ==  "s" or y == "Scissors" or y == "SCISSORS" or y == "scissors"):

    return 1
 else:
    if (x == "rock" or x == "r" or x =="R" or x == "Rock" or x == "ROCK") and (y == "P" or y == "p" or y == "paper" or y == "Paper" or y == "PAPER"):

        return 2
    else:
        if (x == "rock" or x =="R" or x == "r" or x == "Rock" or x == "ROCK") and (y == "rock" or y =="R" or y == "r" or y =="Rock" or y == "ROCK"):

            return 0
        else: 
            print ("Sorry, I didn't understand your input") 


results (player1, player2)

if results == 1:
    print ("Player 1 wins!")
else:
    if results == 2:
        print("Player 2 wins!")
    else:
        if results == 0:
            print("It was a tie!")
```

Comment: You might benefit from reviewing a tutorial on Python functions - in particular how to call them. This is the official one, there are others out there: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Also please don't extend if statements that much. Try something like `rock_list = ["rock","R","r"]` and  `if x in rock_list:` this looks better but it's only style thing so still your choice to use it or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value isn't automatically stored anywhere. You need to store it manually:

```
result = results(player1, player2)

if result == 1:
    ...
```

If you look up at the top of your code, you'll see you already did the right thing with the `input` function:

```
player1 = input ("Player 1: Please enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors:")
```

Functions you define yourself should be handled the same way.

---

In response to the edit: Creating a local variable inside `results` won't help. The code that calls the function needs to store the return value. (People have designed languages that work the way you're trying to get it to work. The result is a huge headache with unrelated parts of the program stomping over each other's data.)

Comment: How do I get the local return variable to be universal?

Comment: @Keith: See expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks I got it

winner = results (player1, player2)